# Is there a Phonegap plugin like Email Composer for Android?

Tags: javascript, html, email, cordova

I'm writing a Phonegap + Sencha Touch application in which I will have to send email. I see that Phonegap has an iPhone plugin for sending email called EMail Composer. Is there an android equivalent for this plugin, because I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have not see the Email Composer, would the WebIntent plugin help @
 http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a mailto url. It has to be trickered by a link click (not thru javascript call).